# React 18 validating child components and disabling/enabling button in parent using data driven components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having issues with creating validation for child components which if invalid should disable the submit button within the parent component. The components are dynamic and are driven from backend service.

So in the example below I have the main code for rendering components. I am using sliderInput component for now which renders on the page. This is rendered twice on the same page as there are two inputs there. But what i want to achieve is to validate each seperately and set a isValid state in the parent but also need to show the error message under the input.

The first bit of code is the parent component

```
 <div className="container mx-auto p-4 rounded-lg">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2">
                    <Panel backgroundColor="bg-slate-400" heightClass="h-60 md:h-auto">
                        {loading && <LoadingPulse />}
                        {!loading && <MessageBubble bubbleText={bubbleText} />}
                    </Panel>
                    <Panel heightClass="h-fit md:h-auto p-8">
                        {loading && <LoadingPulse />}
                        {!loading &&
                            <div>
                                {componentList.map((item, index) => {
                                    if(item) {
                                        const Component = Object.values(item.componentName)[1];

                                        const elementId = item.elementId || '';

                                        return (
                                            <Component {...item }
                                                onStateChange={(childState: any) => handleChildStateChange(childState, elementId)} onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={childRef}/>
                                        );
                                    }
                                })}
                            </div>
                        }
                        {/*{!loading && <MessageBubble />}*/}
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded disabled:opacity-50"
                            disabled={!isFormValid} // Disable button if form is invalid
                        >
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </Panel>
                </form>
            </div>
```

The SliderInput is below:

```
import React, {forwardRef, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {LooseObject} from "../interfaces";

export interface ChildComponentProp {
    validate:() => boolean;
    [key: string]: any;
}
export const Slider: React.FC = forwardRef<ChildComponentProp>((props: LooseObject, ) => {

    const {attributes, content, elementId, onStateChange, validations, key} = props;

    const {required, minValue, maxValue, requiredMessage} = validations;

    const {value, stepIncrement} = attributes;

    const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState<number>(value);
    const [textBoxValue, setTextBoxValue] = useState<string>(value);
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState<boolean>(false);

    // const validate = (): boolean => {
    //     console.log("text box validate", textBoxValue)
    //     if(textBoxValue === "" || textBoxValue  <= minValue || sliderValue > maxValue) {
    //         setIsValid(true);
    //         return false;
    //     }
    //
    //     setError(null);
    //     return true;
    // }

    const handleSliderChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const value = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
        setSliderValue(value);
        setTextBoxValue(value.toString());
        onStateChange(value.toString());
        setError(null);
    };

    const handleTextBoxChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        setTextBoxValue(value);

        const parsedValue = parseInt(value, 10);
        if (!isNaN(parsedValue)) {
            setSliderValue(parsedValue);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        onStateChange(sliderValue);
    }, [sliderValue]);

    return (
        <div className="p-4">
            <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mt-4 mb-2" htmlFor="textBox">
                {content}
            </label>
            <div>
                {attributes.currency === "GBP" && (<span>£</span>)}
                <input
                    id={`${elementId}-input`}
                    type="number"
                    value={textBoxValue}
                    onChange={handleTextBoxChange}
                    className="w-40 border p-2"
                    required
                    key={`${elementId}-input`}
                />
            </div>
            <input
                id={elementId}
                type="range"
                min={minValue}
                max={maxValue}
                value={sliderValue}
                onChange={handleSliderChange}
                className="w-full mt-4"
                aria-label={attributes.ariaLabel}
                step={stepIncrement}
                key={elementId}
            />
            <span>{error !== "" && <p className="text-red-500 text-sm">{error}</p>}</span>
        </div>
    );
});
```

How can i achieve this on change of field or Onblur of input?